# scala Error handling inside a function

Tags: scala, error-handling, try-catch, user-defined-functions

I am having a trouble with my scala code below:

```
class ClassMyHelper {

  protected var logger: Logger = LogManager.getLogger(classOf[AvroHelper])

   def somefunc(schema: Schema, datum: GenericRecord): Array[Byte] = {
    <code>
    var byteData: Array[Byte] = null
    try {
      <code>
      byteData = os.toByteArray()
      //byteData
    } catch {
      case e: IOException =>
        logger.error("IOException encountered!! ", e)

      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error("Something went wrong!! ", e)

    } finally try os.close()
    catch {
      case e: IOException =>
        logger.error("IOException encountered while closing output stream!! ", e)

      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error("Something went wrong while closing output stream!! ", e)

    }
    byteData //Unreachable code
  }
}
```

The problem is that the last line in the somefunc function I am getting an unreachable code error.
Can you please help me in identifying what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `finally {}` after the 2nd `catch` block things appear to clear up. I'm not sure why. I never use `try/catch/finally` myself. I prefer the Scala `Try` class from the Standard Library.

BTW, next time you post code please include the required `import`s, and check to make sure your code compiles as presented.